# Mosek C-API using MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, mosek

I try to build the 'lo1' Example for `Mosek` on `MinGW`. Unfortunately, it keeps returning *`undefined reference to ...`* I think I'm doing something wrong when linking the libraries. Anyone can help?

My build commands are the following:

```
g++ "-IC:\Program Files\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win64x86\h" "-LC:\Program Files\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win64x86\bin" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "lo1.o" "lo1.cpp" "-lmosek64_7_1" 

g++ "-LC:\Program Files\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win64x86\bin" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o lo1.exe "lo1.o" "-lmosek64_7_1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win32x86\h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "lo1.o" "lo1.cpp" 

g++ "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\Mosek\7\tools\platform\win32x86\bin" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o lo1.exe "lo1.o" "-lmosek7_1"
```

Thanks for your answer. the problem happened while building. 
The 64bit version did not work. Mosek 32bit works with MinGW. Above build commands were used.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem happening while building or while running the final binary?

Are you sure g++ builds a 64bit binary. Maybe you should add a -m64

Comment: The -m64 is to tell you build 64 bit binary.